# How to extend a class and override a method which is from interface?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

I have the following scenario:

- interface `IShape` defines method `Draw`.
- class `Circle` implements `IShape` and the method `Draw`.
- class `Rectangle` implements `IShape` and the method `Draw`.
- class `Square` extends `Rectangle` and overrides the method `Draw`.

I wrote the code as following for the above scenario:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) { }
}

public interface IShape
{
    void Draw();
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
    public void Draw()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Rectangle : IShape
{
    public void Draw()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}

public class Square : Rectangle
{
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I am unable to get the last scenario which is `class Square extends Rectangle and overrides the method Draw`.

Any help?

Comment: You should mark `Draw` method in `Rectangle` as `virtual` to be able override it in derived classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rectangle.Draw virtual, Square.Draw override

```
public class Rectangle : IShape
{
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}

public class Square : Rectangle
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```